# HTML datalist tag is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a password generator with HTML, CSS and JS. It allows user to pick their password length from a dropdown input field. However, somehow the `datalist` tag I have used for it, is not working. It shows the input field but not with the dropdown button. Any help would be nice.
***HTML Code***

```html
<form action="" class="my-form">
  <label for="browser">Password length: </label>
  <input list="passList" name="passList" id="passList">

  <datalist id="passList">
                <option value="8">
                <option value="10">
                <option value="12">
                <option value="14">
                <option value="16">
                <option value="18">
   </datalist>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I have figured it out, 2 elements **cannot** have the `same id` so that is why it is not working.

The `input` tag and `datalist` tag have **same id** so it causes trouble so in order for that to work, I have changed the id of input tag.

Comment: Yes. Do make sure that you always use different IDs for every single HTML element. IDs have to be unique. :)

Comment: Like This

Example: (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist)

Comment: Thanks, I had the very same mistake!!